# How to migrate from Vista to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, windows-vista

If I have a Widows (Vista) machine and I want to install Ubuntu and run both OSes. How do I do that? Advisable yes/no and why?

I tried Ubuntu a great many years ago and would like to do so again but am not a techie.

Any help you can give, or point me to a good source as to how to do this, would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

**Advisable: yes.**  The sunset date for Vista is on 11 April 2017 so you'd better start now. I did the same thing a year ago and deleted Vista about 6 months ago.

**Some advice on strategy:**

1. Install all the open source software you can find that can replace your current software on the Vista machine *and make them the default!* (One per week, so you get the hang of them)

   - VLC for video playing
   - LibreOffice for Office automation
   - FileZilla for FTP stuff
   - Firefox as a web browser
   - Evolution / Thunderbird for mail
   - qBittorrent
   - GIMP
   - gedit
2. Download the [end-user manual](https://ubuntu-manual.org/).
3. Backup your entire system using the [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org) Live CD (use disk-to-image) before you start on an external HDD!
4. Delete/off-load unimportant files on the same external HDD.
5. Shrink the Windows partition using `gparted` from the Ubuntu Live CD so there is at least 24GB for the Ubuntu partition available
6. Create 3 partitions for Ubuntu: `swap` ([look here how to calculate your RAM size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1-128gb-ram-on-14-04)) `/` (24GB at least) and then move your `/home` directory on the same "drive" as you currently store the windows "users" directory (probably `c:\users`)

**How to install Ubuntu**: [click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)